# How to find two items of a list with the same return value of a function on their attribute?

Tags: python

Given a basic class `Item`:

```
class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
```

a list of objects of this class (the number of items can be much larger):

```
items = [ Item(0), Item(11), Item(25), Item(16), Item(31) ]
```

and a function `compute` that process and return a value.

How to find two items of this list for which the function `compute` return the same value when using the attribute `val`? If nothing is found, an exception should be raised. If there are more than two items that match, simple return any two of them.

For example, let's define `compute`:

```
def compute( x ):
    return x % 10
```

The excepted pair would be: `(Item(11), Item(31))`.

Comment: Do you want to return the first or all pairs? What happens if there is a 3 items that `compute()` to the same, would you expect all 3 or just when you get a pair?

Comment: @AChampion It would be the first pair found. If there are three items that have the same output value for `compute`, only the two firsts will be returned. I will update the question!

Comment: @AChampion Afterthought, it is not mandatory that the pair is the two first elements that match. It could be any two elements of the list. If there are more than two elements, just return two of them :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the values returned by `compute` are hashable (e.g., `float` values), you can use a dict to store results.

And you don't need to do anything fancy, like a multidict storing all items that produce a result. As soon as you see a duplicate, you're done. Besides being simpler, this also means we short-circuit the search as soon as we find a match, without even calling `compute` on the rest of the elements.

```
def find_pair(items, compute):
    results = {}
    for item in items:
        result = compute(item.val)
        if result in results:
            return results[result], item
        results[result] = item
    raise ValueError('No pair of items')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The difference with [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51316066/10067842) is that you use `result in results` and I use `dict.get()`. Do you think both are ok in term of efficiency?

Comment: @anonom They're algorithmically the same. The micro-efficiency will almost never make a difference. In the rare cases where it does, you need to test (and also compare `except KeyError:`) and see which is fastest on your actual data. But normally, you should worry about correctness first (e.g., you can't do just `d.get(key)` if the values can be `None`), readability second (my code seems simpler to me, but there's always a subjective component to readability), and micro-optimizing third, if even that.

Comment: @anonom With the examples from your question, I get 1.16us for my code, 1.61us for my code modified to use `get` and `if not None:` the way yours does. So, for this data, `in` is clearly faster. But half a microsecond is probably not a good reason to choose it, if you understand your version better. (By the way, your actual code takes 1.67us if I wrap it in a function, 1.81us if I run it at global level. I assume the first 60ns is caused by not doing an early `return`, and the additional 140ns by looking up `items` and `compute` as globals instead of locals.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the length of the set of resulting values:

```
class Item(object):
  def __init__(self, val):
    self.val = val
  def __repr__(self):
    return f'Item({self.val})'

def compute(x):
  return x%10

items = [ Item(0), Item(11), Item(25), Item(16), Item(31)]
c = list(map(lambda x:compute(x.val), items))
if len(set(c)) == len(c): #no two or more equal values exist in the list
  raise Exception("All elements have unique computational results")
```

To find values with similar computational results, a dictionary can be used:

```
from collections import Counter
new_d = {i:compute(i.val) for i in items}
d = Counter(new_d.values())
multiple = [a for a, b in new_d.items() if d[b] > 1]
```

Output:

```
[Item(11), Item(31)]
```

A slightly more efficient way to find if multiple objects of the same computational value exist is to use `any`, requiring a single pass over the `Counter` object, whereas using a `set` with `len` requires several iterations:

```
if all(b == 1 for b in d.values()):
   raise Exception("All elements have unique computational results")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In your code `compute` takes an `Item` as parameter, but in my question `compute` just takes the value, so I think in order to `map` `items`, `compute` should be wrapped. Also, as `items` can be very large, is it that efficient to `map` and `set` all these elements?Otherwise, it's interesting to see that `Counter` can be used here! But the goal is to get the two `Item`s, not their value. Is it possible to use `Counter` and get the objects instead of their `val`? I can't think of a way to do it.

Comment: @anonom Please see my recent edit. However, would it not be more efficient to declare `compute` so that it is passed the object, rather than the integer value? Passing the object means `items` only has to be iterated over once. Note I added a `__repr__` method in `Item` to increase readability.

Comment: Interesting edit! It's true that if `compute` gets directly the object, it would be more efficient, but `compute` is not a function particularly bounded to `Item`, it could be used for any other value (say, I have also a class `Foo` with the attribute `bar` and would like to use `compute` on this attribute).

Comment: @anonom That makes sense. Please see my recent edit, as I used a `lambda` in `map` to access the attribute of the current value of iteration being passed to the function in `map`.

Comment: Nicely done with the lambda! For the `Counter`, how would you handle it if there are more than two items in `multiple`? I only need two items. Maybe `multiple[:2]` or using `itertools.islice` for more efficiency?

Comment: @anonom `multiple[:2]` would certainly work. However, you would not be using the other data values in the list. Are there any specific rules that are determining which values to keep, and which to discard? Implementing a version of the rules when finding the values in `multiple` might be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary `val_to_it` that contains `Item`s keyed by computed `val` can be used:

```
val_to_it = {}
for it in items:
    computed_val = compute(it.val)
    # Check if an Item in val_to_it has the same computed val
    dict_it = val_to_it.get(computed_val)
    if dict_it is None:
        # If not, add it to val_to_it so it can be referred to 
        val_to_it[computed_val] = it
    else:
        # We found the two elements!
        res = [dict_it, it]
        break
else:
    raise Exception( "Can't find two items" )
```

The `for` block can be rewrite to handle `n` number of elements:

```
for it in items:
    computed_val = compute(it.val)
    dict_lit = val_to_it.get(computed_val)
    if dict_lit is None:
        val_to_it[computed_val] = [it]
    else:
        dict_lit.append(it)
        # Check if we have the expected number of elements
        if len(dict_lit) == n:
            # Found n elements!
            res = dict_lit
            break
```